# Expectation function does evaluate my expression

Tags: evaluation, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to evaluate the expression

```
Expectation[(B x (-6 b + 12 a n0 + B x + B^2 x^2))/(2 (6 a + B x + B^2 x^2)), 
  Distributed[x, BetaDistribution[α, β]]]
```

The evaluation runs for a few seconds and then *Mathematica* displays the unevaluated expression without any error messages or any other output. Is this because this random variable transformation is too complex for *Mathematica* to handle? If so, shouldn't some message be generated?

#### Edit

The same expression with an `UniformDistribution`

```
Expectation[(B x (-6 b + 12 a n0 + B x + B^2 x^2))/(2 (6 a + B x + B^2 x^2)), 
  Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{α, β}]]]
```

completes and returns a formula.

Comment: I think you will have to tell us how all the free variables in your `Expectation` expression are defined before we can help you.

Comment: All they are positive numbers. I have no more constrains, I am trying to find a general formula for the expectation with a,b,B and n0 as parameters.

Comment: @m_goldberg That would only be necessary if it concerned `NExpectation`.

Comment: Returning unevaluated when no result could be obtained is a standard procedure in Mathematica . Try for instance `Integrate[Sin[Sin[x]], x]`. I believe it is in fact related to the core of Mathematica as a pattern matcher / rule user. It returns what it has got when it doesn't have any remaining rule to apply.

Comment: Note that Expectation effortlessly finds the expectation of a polynomial in x with non-numeric coefficients. I guess your expression is just a bit to complicated.

Comment: I agree with Sjoerd. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9292/4330) is a related question. There the expectation is much simpler but *Mathematica* also does not give a result. There, I do not understand why it does not give `Infinity`. After some more testing I found the following peculiar case. `Expectation[Abs[x], x \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]` evaluates to `0`, even though `PDF[CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]` shows that this should not be so..

Comment: But as is shown in the comments to the [answer by Sacha](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9293/4330), that could be resolved by `SetOptions[Expectation, GenerateConditions -> True]`. Sorry, this has little to do with this Q&A, except that it adds to my suspicion that `Expectation` is in general a bit dodgy, especially if you do not know about this option.

Comment: Thank guys, I guess I will have to go back to pen, paper and coffee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's write out the expectation as an integral. We first write the rational function in a more canonical form:
$$ 
    R(x) = \frac{B}{2} x +  \frac{3 B x}{B^2 x^2+B x+ 6 a}\left(2 a n_0 -a-b\right)
$$
Clearly, then:
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(R(X)\right) = \frac{B}{2} \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} + B \left( n_0 -\frac{a+b}{2 a}\right) \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{6 a X}{B^2 X^2+B X+ 6 a}\right)
$$
The remaining rational function can be decomposed into a series using [Chebyshev's polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials):
$$ \begin{align}
  \frac{6 a x}{B^2 x^2+B x+ 6 a} &= x \frac{1}{1 + 2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{24 a}} \left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{6a}} x\right) +  \left( \frac{B}{\sqrt{6a}} x\right)^2 } \\ &= x \sum_{n=0}^\infty U_n\left( -\sqrt{\frac{1}{24 a}} \right) \left( \frac{B}{\sqrt{6a}} x\right)^n
\end{align}
$$
where $U_n(x)$ denotes Chebyshev polynomials of the [second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html). Hence, in some open region of the parameter space, where the interchanging of the sum and the expectation is warranted, we have:
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(R(X)\right) = \frac{B}{2} \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} + B \left( n_0 -\frac{a+b}{2 a}\right) \sum_{n=0}^\infty U_n\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{24 a}}  \right) \left( \frac{B}{\sqrt{6a}}\right)^n \frac{ \left(\alpha\right)_{n+1}}{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)_{n+1}}
$$
where $\left(a\right)_n$ denotes Pochhammer's symbol, as comes from 
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left(X^{n+1}\right)  = \frac{ \left(\alpha\right)_{n+1}}{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)_{n+1}}
$$

Here is a numerical confirmation in *Mathematica*:

```
In[44]:= Block[{al = 2, be = 3, B = 1/3, a = 1, n0 = 1, b = 2/3}, 
 NExpectation[(B x (-6 b + 12 a n0 + B x + B^2 x^2))/(2 (6 a + B x + 
       B^2 x^2)), Distributed[x, BetaDistribution[al, be]]]]

Out[44]= 0.0881815

In[43]:= Block[{al = 2, be = 3, B = 1/3, a = 1`, n0 = 1, b = 2/3, 
   nmax = 500}, 
  B/2 al/(al + be) + 
   B (n0 - (a + b)/(2 a)) Sum[
     ChebyshevU[n, -Sqrt[(1/(24 a))]] (B/Sqrt[6 a])^
      n Pochhammer[al, n + 1]/Pochhammer[al + be, n + 1], {n, 0, 
      nmax}]] // N

Out[43]= 0.0881815
```

<strike>It is unlikely that this particular sum admits a closed form evaluation.</strike>

**EDIT**
It was pointed out to me that *Mathematica* can actually evaluate the sum:

```
In[9]:= Sum[
 ChebyshevU[n, -Sqrt[1/(24*a)]]*(B/Sqrt[6*a])^
   n*(Pochhammer[α, n + 1]/
        Pochhammer[α + β, n + 1]), {n, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> α > 0 && β > 0 && a > 0 && B > 0]

Out[9]= (12*I*Sqrt[6]*a*Gamma[1 + α]*Gamma[α + β]*
    Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + α, 1 + α + β,
          -((2*B)/(Sqrt[a]*(Sqrt[1/a] + I*Sqrt[(-1 + 24*a)/a])))] -
      I*Sqrt[6]*Gamma[1 + α]*Gamma[α + β]*
    Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + α, 1 + α + β,
          -(((Sqrt[1/a] + I*Sqrt[(-1 + 24*a)/a])*B)/(12*Sqrt[a]))] +
      12*I*Sqrt[6]*a*Gamma[1 + α]*Gamma[α + β]*
    Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + α, 1 + α + β,
          -(((Sqrt[1/a] + I*Sqrt[(-1 + 24*a)/a])*B)/(12*Sqrt[a]))] +
      (Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[(-1 + 24*a)/a]*Gamma[1 + α]*
      Gamma[α + β]*
      Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + α,
       1 + α + β, -(((Sqrt[1/a] + I*Sqrt[(-1 + 24*a)/a])*
            B)/
                  (12*Sqrt[a]))])/Sqrt[1/a])/(Sqrt[
    12 - Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[1/a]]*
      Sqrt[12 + Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[1/a]]*
   a*(Sqrt[1/a] + I*Sqrt[(-1 + 24*a)/a])*Gamma[α]*
      Gamma[1 + α + β])
```

Comment: Lucid analysis indeed (+1). Thank you.